# Pagination Click and Bad request

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.3

I'm using **Cakephp 2.3.0** and when I am clicking on Dashboard link Active Admins it goes to Admin index page and giving list of active admins. But when I am clicking 2nd page it is giving '**Bad request**'. And the link is changing.

first page link is :

```
Admins/index/conditions%3AAdmin.is_active%3D1
```

Second page link is :

```
Admins/index/conditions%5BAND%5D%5BAdmin.is_active%20LIKE%5D:%251%25/page:2
```

How can I rectify this problem. Please help anyone.

Thanks